# How to trigger html code (modal popup) from OnPost handler in razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, modal-dialog, razor-pages

Most of the time we are hitting submit button and triggering OnPost handler to do some stuff. I need to do something opposite. I would like to trigger the modal(html code) after OnPost is executed only if `ModelState.IsValid` .
How to do achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use ajax to pass form data to OnPost handler,and then check `ModelState` and pass data to the view,if `ModelState.IsValid`,open the modal,here is a demo:

cshtml:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input name="name" value="test" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitForm()"/>
</form>
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "?handler=Test",
                data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == "open") {
                        $("#myModal").modal("show");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    </script>

}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
 public JsonResult OnPostTest(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new JsonResult("open");
            }
            return new JsonResult("");
        }
```

User:

```
public class User {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. However my TempData js-notyfication no longer working after using ajax script. Also when ModelState is false, code in my OnPost handler in .cs is ignored.
Then I would like to redirect the user to google.com after he hit the close button in the modal window but anything i did didn't work.  <a href="www.google.com" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">RedirectTOGoGle</a>